# How do I disconnect Vuetify v-intersect observer in component beforeDestroy hook?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using `v-intersect` to modify the NavBar content based on the scrolling event. The data is then recorded to Vuex Store. Problem is when navigate to a different route, `v-intersect` fire the event and modify the Store which changed the NavBar content unexpectedly. `v-intersect.once` is not applicable to my use case, but I'd like to know how to disconnect `v-intersect` observer from the `beforeDestroy` hook?

```js
<template>
  ...
  <div v-intersect="intersect" />
  ...
</template>

<script>
import { mapFields } from 'vuex-map-fields'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapFields(['isIntersecting']),
  },
  methods: {
    intersect(entries, observer) {
      this.isIntersecting = !!entries[0].intersectionRatio
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: The `v-intersect` directive already [unobserves its element when it's unmounted](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/58db08e/packages/vuetify/src/directives/intersect/index.ts#L70), which occurs *before* the parent component is unmounted. Can you share a link to a reproduction where the Intersection Observer fires after the component has unmounted?

Comment: @tony19 As Estus Flask explained it's a race condition on destroy. v-intersect unobserve the element when unmounting, but before unmount it fires event on route change. His solution was able to solve this problem.

Comment: `but before unmount it fires event on route change` I can't reproduce the behavior you're describing so I'm curious what you're doing differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive instance is supposed to be destroyed and so disconnected when a parent is destroyed, this is the only proper way for a directive to work.

To stop receiving events, `v-if` can be used, or events can be conditionally processed. The second option is applicable if there's race condition on destroy, so the behaviour needs to be applied immediately:

```
beforeDestroy() {
  this.isIntersectionInactive = false;
}
...
intersect(entries, observer) {
  if (this.isIntersectionInactive)
    return;

  this.isIntersecting = !!entries[0].intersectionRatio
},
```